# Connecting NSTableView's delegate and dataSource to a custom subclass?

Tags: swift, nstableview

My app reads text files into `[Card]`. Each Card has a two-letter code at the front, and I break up the cards into different NSTableViews depending on that code. That lets me set the layout in IB so each group of cards has an appropriate display.

I used to have all of the controller code in a single VC, but as the number of tables grew, so did the complexity of this code. Since the views differ primarily in layout and some default settings, they can all descend from a single class. So I did:

```
class CardView: NSTableView, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate { ...
```

and, for one example...

```
class GeometryView: CardView { ...
```

Then I went to IB, selected the tableview, and changed it's class to GeometryView. Now I have to set up the delegate and dataSource, and this is where I have my problem : IB will not allow me to drag either setting to either the GeometryView or CardView.

So... do the targets of these IB settings have to be a particular subclass, say NSViewController? Or is there something I'm missing that lets IB see these as targets? I didn't do anything in the original VC, it just worked. Or am I simply doing the wrong thing in IB?

In this image you can see the tableview on the far left, the custom view subclass in the helper, and the connections for the tableview on the right. Any attempt to drag from the connections to anywhere in the helper fails. Note that the two existing connections are to the former delegate VC, which is what I am trying to replace.

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot of what you are trying to do, there should be no problem at linking the delegate or datasource using IB in the way you described.

Comment: I don't see the problem from the screenshot, here's one of how it should look like https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxUbHGaoHgxtcUwxTE44Z2FrdlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @A-Live: there is a difference between the two - it seems you have a tableview in a tableview? My tableview, which I created in IB, is inside a ClipView. In your case you are connecting the tableView's delegate to some other object, whereas in my case it is the same object. I don't believe that will work in your example either - try dragging to "Table View".

Comment: This is a standard table view created at IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why Interface Builder won't let you connect the delegate or data source to itself, but you could do it programatically. The `awakeFromNib` method is probably the best place for this, as it's called after both `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    delegate = self
    dataSource = self

    super.awakeFromNib()
}
```

Comment: Very useful! Do you know what the default is? Is the default delegate, for instance, "self" or "nil"?

Comment: Ok I C&Ped that code into my base class, the `class CardView: NSTableView, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate`, but it responds "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable. I assume the `self` is not the one on the right, but the invisible one on the left, `self.dataSource`.

Comment: Ahhh, it's self.setDelegate(self), etc.

Comment: `self` is immutable? That's weird. I'm an iOS programmer and there my code works fine. And as far as I know, `self.setDelegate(self)` and `self.delegate = self` are equivalent in Swift...

Comment: Yeah that is kinda strange isn't it. I'm filing it in radar.